# Heroku app name rename still references the old app url

Tags: wordpress, heroku

I have renamed my app from Heroku on which I was hosting a Wordpress instance and now the old app is still being referenced, and I tried:

- `heroku restart`,
- changing the `remote` for git to point to the new `heroku app name`,
- checking that the ClearDB is still working and pointing to the new app name,
- `purge` old build cache for a new build cache,

None of the above have worked,

Do not know what is meant to be done for me to see the new app name and not the old files,

Comment: A couple possibilies come to mind possibilities: 1) There is a reference to it within your code. 2) Your domain name references the old version (and is caching the old version, actually this could be just a general caching issue).

Comment: @Nuclearman I just noticed that it appears to be a Heroku problem with deleting a "dynos" files, after deleting a project all together. As upon deleting and re-creating an empty project with the same name as the previously deleted project, the old files & old project name ```...herokuapp.com``` is still being loaded for no particular reason :/ and the same goes for any other project I delete and re-create with the same name. Don't know what the issue is with Heroku but it is quite annoying and do not know how long I should wait for it to disappear...